# How put a product display on the "Shop" not the "Home" page?

Tags: commerce

I have created all suggested types and objects for a *product display* (drupal commerce module) but it only shows on the "Home" page (which I have renamed "News"). I have a page named "Shop" for this purpose i.e. where I want the products to be on. How do I tell drupal to place the product display there?

Test site: http://marius-raphaelius.com/drup

(In fact, how does one edit the content of a page in general?)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to tell Drupal to use a different node for the home page.   If this is what you mean you can do this by going to

Home -> Administer -> Site Configuration

You can change the node for the Default front page there.

Comment: Thanks but I don't think so, the home page (News) is fine, what I want is that the products display on the Shop page, not on News. Or else I'm completely misunderstanding the concept of front = home page.